# How to use one AsyncTask Class to apply different Activity in Android

Tags: android

I have a AsyncTask class that connect to web service to get something and then print to the screen.
Here is my code:

```
public class GetCreditAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String>{
   private MainActivity callerActivity;
   private String credit;
   public GetCreditAsyncTask(Context context){
        callerActivity = (MainActivity )context;
    }
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) { 
         .....//do something and get the credit
}
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
          callerActivity.txtView.setText(credit);
   }


}
```

It works perfect but now, I have one more Activity `ProfileActivity`
which also want to use `GetCreditAsyncTask` to get the credit and print it to the `txtView`,
but at the begining of `GetCreditAsyncTask`, I cast the `callerActivity` to `MainActivity`.
The question is how to just use one AsyncTask class so that I can call it and get the credit.

Comment: As an alternative to the interface solution suggested by @FlávioFaria, you can also make the `GetCreditAsyncTask` an abstract class which only contains the shared logic for `doInBackGround(...)`. Then in your activities you can extend this task and provide implementations for `onPreExecute(...` and `onPostExecute(...)` that are specific to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface that both activities implement. Instead of casting to MainActivity, you must cast to this interface.

```
public interface ActivityListener {
   public void setText(String text);
}


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActivityListener {

...

    public void setText(String text) {
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}


public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements ActivityListener {

...

    public void setText(String text) {
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.secondary_text);
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}


public class GetCreditAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String>{
   private ActivityListener callerActivity;
   private String credit;
   public GetCreditAsyncTask(Context context){
        callerActivity = (ActivityListener) context;
    }
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) { 
         .....//do something and get the credit
}
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
          callerActivity.setText(credit);
   }


}
```